# Passing a function as a prop to a functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass a function as a prop into a functional React component. I keep getting the error `logThis is not a function`.

The parent component is a class component with a function `logToConsole`. I summarized the code below:

```
logToConsole = (value) => {
  console.log(value)
}
render(){
  return(
    <ChildComp logThis={this.logToConsole} />
  )
}
```

The ChildComp is:

```
const ChildComp = (logThis) => (
  <button onClick={()=>logThis('test string')}>Click Here</button>
)

export default ChildComp
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The first parameter `logThis` will be props object itself.You need to destructure the `logThis` object.

```
const ChildComp = ({ logThis }) => (
  <button onClick={() => logThis('test string')}>Click Here</button>
)
```

Or you can access it from `props`

```
const ChildComp = (props) => (
  <button onClick={() => props.logThis('test string')}>Click Here</button>
)
```

Comment: Can someone tell how to add this function above in another function not in jsx, this.logThis() give error props.logThis() also give error

Answer (score 3):

destructure logThis from props

```
const ChildComp = ({logThis}) => (
  <button onClick={()=>logThis('test string')}>Click Here</button>
)

export default ChildComp
```

Answer (score 2):

Change to:

```
const ChildComp = (props) => (
  <button onClick={()=>props.logThis('test string')}>Click Here</button>
)

export default ChildComp
```