# React mfe: Communication between mfe's

Tags: reactjs, callback, subscribe

With react 17, I am trying with a mfe demo. There is a parent container that contains two mfe's, Header and Auth.
[image]

When user logs in, the container is notified. Upon receiving this notification, the header component needs to be notified about this event and allows to update itself.

Currently the container could get the message from **Auth-mfe** but got struck with how the **Header** component to subscribe to this with container.

The goal is to minimize or eliminate direct communication between mfe's and if any needed, it has to go through the parent container.

I am not using redux or any third party library for storing the state. The user session details are currently stored in sessionStorage by **Auth-mfe**.

Container app.js snippet is

```
function App() {
return (
    <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                <Header notifySignedIn={notifySignedIn} />
                <Suspense fallback={<Progress />}>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/auth" render={props => (<AuthLazy onSignin={onSignin} {...props} /> )} />
                    </Switch>
                </Suspense>
                <Footer />
            </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

}

export default App;

Comment: I made some progress by passing function as props which takes in the subscribed function as parameter. This way, the header can be notified from the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55873055/passing-a-function-as-a-prop-to-a-functional-component/55873077) , I implemented passing the callback function from container => header and in turn header will pass the subscribe function back to the container. This way it works.
[image]

Comment: If you don't mine then could you please share POC's with us and source code. it will help to other as well

Answer (score 0):

```
    //add the code in componentdidmount where you want to receive the data
window.addEventListener("event-name", (datarecieved)=> {
    console.log(datarecieved.detail);
}, false);

//Create an event to pass data
let send-data = new CustomEvent("event-name", {detail: "Hi Suraj here"});
window.dispatchEvent(send-data);
```