# What may cause a function to not be recognized as a function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I'm starting studying React and I was following this YouTube tutorial of a TO DO LIST using React.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E1E08i2UJGI

My form loads perfectly, but if I write something and press any button I get the message: "completedTask is not a function". The same goes for buttons that call a function 'removeTask' and 'setEdit'.
I don't understand the reason I'm getting such error message. In the tutorial it works when the buttons are clicked. I've read in some forums that it would be related to the fact that you can't use map on Objects (non-array elements), but I didn't understand it very well and I don't know how to fix it. And the most mysterious parte: why does his code work and mine do not?
Could anybody please explain it?

Obs1: I found in another post that `return tasks.tasks.map((task, index)` solved the problem for 'task.map is not a function' error message in TASK.JS. I'm using it instead of `return tasks.map((task, index)` but I also didn't understant the reason.

Obs2: I don't think it makes any difference for the error message, but I used the button tag instead using React Icons as the video suggests.

```
=== TASKLIST.JS ===

import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Task from './Task'
import TaskForm from './TaskForm'


function TaskList() {

    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

    const addTask = task => {
        if(!task.text || /^\s*$/.test(task.text)) {
            return
        }
        const newTasks = [task, ...tasks];

        setTasks(newTasks);

    };

    const updateTask = (taskId, newValue) => {
        if(!newValue.text || /^\s*$/.test(newValue.text)) {
            return
        }
        
        setTasks(prev => prev.map(item => (item.id === taskId ? newValue : item)));
    };

    const removeTask = id => {
        const removeArr = [...tasks].filter(task => task.id !== id);

        setTasks(removeArr)
    };

    const completedTask = id => {
        let updatedTasks = tasks.map(task => {
            if (task.id === id) {
                task.isComplete = !task.isComplete
            }
            return task
        })
        setTasks(updatedTasks);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Cabeçalho</h1>
            <TaskForm onSubmit={addTask}/>
            <Task 
                tasks={tasks}
                completedTask={completedTask} 
                removeTask={removeTask}
                updateTask={updateTask} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default TaskList
```

```
=== TASK.JS ===

import React, { useState } from 'react'
import TaskForm from './TaskForm'

function Task(tasks, completedTask, removeTask, updateTask) {

    const [edit, setEdit] = useState({
        id: null,
        value: ''
    })

    const submitUpdate = value => {
        updateTask(edit.id, value)
        setEdit({
            id: null,
            value: ''
        })
    }
    
    if (edit.id) {
        return <TaskForm edit={edit} onSubmit={submitUpdate} />;

    }

    return tasks.tasks.map((task, index) => (
        <div className={task.isComplete ? 'task-row complete' : 'task-row'} key={index}>
            {task.text}
            <div className="buttons">
                <button onClick={() => completedTask(task.id)} className='completed-icon'>done</button>
                <button onClick={() => removeTask(task.id)} className='delete-icon'>delete</button>
                <button onClick={() => setEdit({id: task.id, value: task.text})} className='edit-icon'>edit</button>
            </div>
        </div>    
    ))
};

export default Task
```

```
=== TASKFORM.JS ===

import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

function TaskForm(props) {

    const [input, setInput] = useState(props.edit ? props.edit.value : '');

    const inputRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        inputRef.current.focus()
    })

    const handleChange = e => {
        setInput(e.target.value);
    }

    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        props.onSubmit({
            id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000),
            text: input
        });

        setInput('');

    };


    return (
        <form className="task-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            {props.edit ? (
                <>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Update your task" value={input} name="text" className="task-input" onChange={handleChange} ref={inputRef}/>
                <button className="task-button edit" onChange={handleChange}>Update a task</button>
                </>
            ) : (
                <>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Add a new task" value={input} name="text" className="task-input" onChange={handleChange} ref={inputRef}/>
                <button className="task-button" onChange={handleChange}>Add a task</button>
                </>
            )}
            
        </form>
    )
}

export default TaskForm
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing a function as a prop to a functional component](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55873055)

Comment: Tarik's reply fixed the bugs and I'll read the link you suggested.
Thank you, Nick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function Task({ tasks, completedTask, removeTask, updateTask }) {
    // ...
}
```

You can also do this (semantically equivalent):

```js
function Task(props) {
    const { tasks, completedTask, removeTask, updateTask } = props;
    // ...
}
```

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55873077/6301627):

> The first parameter will be props object itself. You need to destructure the object.

You can read more about object destructuring [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring).

Comment: It solved the bugs. I still don't understand what it is doing, but I'll read the link you suggested. Thank you, man.

Comment: @JoãoOrtega It is extracting properties of the object into individual variables. A relatively new syntactic sugar feature.