# Trouble passing a function to a stateless functional component in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm creating a drum machine in React for a freeCodeCamp project. I have the buttons rendered, but cannot get the buttons to play the audio.

I've created a stateless functional component that iterates through an array of objects containing the the audio url and a few other details, creating a keyboard to play the sounds. The function to play the audio is in the app component, and I'm passing the function to the Keyboard as props.

I'm getting an object error in the console, and can't figure out where it's coming from. The CodePen is here (https://codepen.io/cpmcclure/pen/qBXGNpw), and I've copied the code below as well. Any thoughts would help. Thanks in advance!

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.playSound = this.playSound.bind(this);
  }
   playSound = (key) => {
    const audio = document.getElementById(key);
   audio.currentTime = 0;
   audio.play();
   }
  render() {
    return(
        <Keyboard play={this.playSound}/>
    )
  }
}

const Keyboard = ({playSound}) => {
    return TR66.map(sound => {
        return (<button class="drum-pad" id={sound.id} onClick={() => playSound(sound.key)}>
          <audio class="clip" id={sound.key} src={sound.url}/>
            <div>{sound.key}</div>
        </button>)
    });
}

const TR66 = [
  {
    keyCode: 81,
    key: 'Q',
    id: 'Bass Drum',
    url: 'https://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/DRUMS%20(FULL%20KITS)/DRUM%20MACHINES/Roland%20TR-66/15[kb]66-bd-01.wav.mp3'
  },
  {
    keyCode: 87,
    key: 'W',
    id: 'Snare',
    url: 'https://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/DRUMS%20(FULL%20KITS)/DRUM%20MACHINES/Roland%20TR-66/14[kb]66-sd-01.wav.mp3'
  },
  {
    keyCode: 69,
    key: 'E',
    id: 'Hi Hat 1',
    url: 'https://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/DRUMS%20(FULL%20KITS)/DRUM%20MACHINES/Roland%20TR-66/6[kb]66-hh-01-or.wav.mp3'
  },
  {
    keyCode: 65,
    key: 'A',
    id: 'Hi Hat 2',
    url: 'https://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/DRUMS%20(FULL%20KITS)/DRUM%20MACHINES/Roland%20TR-66/5[kb]66-hh-08.wav.mp3'
  },
  {
    keyCode: 83,
    key: 'S',
    id: 'Hi Hat Open 1',
    url: 'https://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/DRUMS%20(FULL%20KITS)/DRUM%20MACHINES/Roland%20TR-66/33[kb]66-hho-01-or.wav.mp3'
  },
  {
    keyCode: 68,
    key: 'D',
    id: 'Hi Hat Open 2',
    url: 'https://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/DRUMS%20(FULL%20KITS)/DRUM%20MACHINES/Roland%20TR-66/37[kb]66-hho-04.wav.mp3'
  },
  {
    keyCode: 90,
    key: 'Z',
    id: 'Wood Block Low',
    url: 'https://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/DRUMS%20(FULL%20KITS)/DRUM%20MACHINES/Roland%20TR-66/26[kb]66-per-08.wav.mp3'
  },
  {
    keyCode: 88,
    key: 'X',
    id: 'Wood Block High',
    url: 'https://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/DRUMS%20(FULL%20KITS)/DRUM%20MACHINES/Roland%20TR-66/12[kb]66-per-03.wav.mp3'
  },
  {
    keyCode: 67,
    key: 'C',
    id: 'Rim',
    url: 'https://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/DRUMS%20(FULL%20KITS)/DRUM%20MACHINES/Roland%20TR-66/11[kb]66-rim-01.wav.mp3'
  }
]

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("drum-machine"))
```

```css
button {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="drum-machine">
</div>
```

Comment: I'd highly recommend adding a couple `debugger;` statements in your functions and using the developer tools to step through the code.

Comment: Two problems I see at first glance: the `<Keyboard />` component should return JSX, not an array of JSX components. Move the map() function into the return value of the function, don't return the result of the map() function. Also, you're passing a `play` prop to `<Keyboard />` but it appears to take a prop called `playSound` instead.

Comment: Thanks @ballmerspeak, I'll look into debuggers! I'm not familiar with them, but that sounds like something essential that I should get under my belt.

Comment: @BrendanBond I think that might be the issue! Using the map function like that seemed weird to me, but it worked, so I went with it. I've seen a few uses of using the curly brackets to destructure props (an answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55873055/passing-a-function-as-a-prop-to-a-functional-component/55873077), but I also previously used props.playSound and had the same issue, so I think it's from the map function.

Comment: Cool, great to hear. Re: destructuring props, though, nothing is wrong with destructuring props at all, but it appears to me (again, at first glance at your code) that you're not destructuring properly. When you render `<Keyboard play={someFunction} />`, you're passing a props object that looks like `{ play: someFunction }`. When you destructure the props in the Keyboard function, they need to be named the same, so your `const Keyboard = ({ playSound }) => {...}` will not do anything with a prop named `play.`

Comment: @BrendanBond thank you for the explanation, that makes destructuring more clear! I'll try to research it a little more before making use of it. I've tried moving the map function into the return (wrapped in curly braces) as well as removing the destructuring (so passing the function in as props, and accessing it as props.playSound), but still not having any luck: https://codepen.io/cpmcclure/pen/qBXGNpw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be a mistake in naming: the component function is `const Keyboard = ({playSound}) => {` but it's created with `<Keyboard play={this.playSound}/>`. The correct match would be `<Keyboard playSound={this.playSound}/>`.

Also, `class` should be `className` and all array child elements need to have unique keys.

I suggest using functional components throughout. No state is necessary, and if it was, you can use the [`useState` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate).

I recommend attaching the audio objects to your drum kit elements. Keeping the kit data self-contained in its own data structure alleviates the burden on your components of rendering `<audio>` elements, then subsequently finding them by id just to play a clip. There's no need to go through the DOM -- instead, you can simply say `kit[i].audio.play()` (`kit` is a generic kit that we fill with the `TR66` set here) once you've set `kit[i] = new Audio(kit[i].url)`.

You can use a document listener for the key triggers, if desired, or attach that listener to the drum machine component alone. This illustrates that having the audio objects in the kit makes it easy to play them from multiple places, although I realize it's jumping ahead a bit on your current code. Remove the `useEffect` if you don't need this.

```js
const App = () => <DrumMachine kit={TR66} />;

const DrumPad = ({text, onPlay}) => (
  <button className="drum-pad" onClick={onPlay}>
    <div>{text}</div>
  </button>
);

const DrumMachine = ({kit}) => {
  const playAudio = audio => {
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    audio.play();
  };
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const listener = e => {
      const drum = kit.find(({key}) => 
        key.toLowerCase() === e.key.toLowerCase()
      );
      drum && playAudio(drum.audio);
    };
    document.addEventListener("keydown", listener);
    return () => document.removeEventListener("keydown", listener);
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div>
      {kit.map(({key, id, audio}) =>
        <DrumPad
          key={id}
          text={key}
          onPlay={() => playAudio(audio)}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const TR66 = [
  {
    keyCode: 81,
    key: 'Q',
    id: 'Bass Drum',
    url: 'https://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/DRUMS%20(FULL%20KITS)/DRUM%20MACHINES/Roland%20TR-66/15[kb]66-bd-01.wav.mp3'
  },
  {
    keyCode: 87,
    key: 'W',
    id: 'Snare',
    url: 'https://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/DRUMS%20(FULL%20KITS)/DRUM%20MACHINES/Roland%20TR-66/14[kb]66-sd-01.wav.mp3'
  },
  {
    keyCode: 69,
    key: 'E',
    id: 'Hi Hat 1',
    url: 'https://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/DRUMS%20(FULL%20KITS)/DRUM%20MACHINES/Roland%20TR-66/6[kb]66-hh-01-or.wav.mp3'
  },
  {
    keyCode: 65,
    key: 'A',
    id: 'Hi Hat 2',
    url: 'https://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/DRUMS%20(FULL%20KITS)/DRUM%20MACHINES/Roland%20TR-66/5[kb]66-hh-08.wav.mp3'
  },
  {
    keyCode: 83,
    key: 'S',
    id: 'Hi Hat Open 1',
    url: 'https://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/DRUMS%20(FULL%20KITS)/DRUM%20MACHINES/Roland%20TR-66/33[kb]66-hho-01-or.wav.mp3'
  },
  {
    keyCode: 68,
    key: 'D',
    id: 'Hi Hat Open 2',
    url: 'https://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/DRUMS%20(FULL%20KITS)/DRUM%20MACHINES/Roland%20TR-66/37[kb]66-hho-04.wav.mp3'
  },
  {
    keyCode: 90,
    key: 'Z',
    id: 'Wood Block Low',
    url: 'https://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/DRUMS%20(FULL%20KITS)/DRUM%20MACHINES/Roland%20TR-66/26[kb]66-per-08.wav.mp3'
  },
  {
    keyCode: 88,
    key: 'X',
    id: 'Wood Block High',
    url: 'https://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/DRUMS%20(FULL%20KITS)/DRUM%20MACHINES/Roland%20TR-66/12[kb]66-per-03.wav.mp3'
  },
  {
    keyCode: 67,
    key: 'C',
    id: 'Rim',
    url: 'https://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/DRUMS%20(FULL%20KITS)/DRUM%20MACHINES/Roland%20TR-66/11[kb]66-rim-01.wav.mp3'
  }
];
TR66.forEach(({url}, i) => {
  TR66[i].audio = new Audio(url);
});

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<App />);
```

```css
button {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```