# How to have a React child component call a function from a parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a parent component and a child component (as a separate component file). How would I go about calling a function in the parent component from the child component?

The child component is imported into the parent component and the parent component has a function that makes an API call. I would like the child component to be able to also reach into the parent and run the api call function.

I could post the code I have but it's simply making an API call in the parent and having the child component imported in the parent.

thanks for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing a function as a prop to a functional component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55873055/passing-a-function-as-a-prop-to-a-functional-component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide the function as a property on the child element:

```js
const Parent = () => {
  const someFunction = () => { /*...*/ };

  return <Child someProp={someFunction}/>;
}

const Child = ({ someProp }) => {
  return (
    <div onClick={() => someProp()}>
      Hello World
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: perfect, thanks!